# Can't Start MySQL EasyPhp 16.1

Tags: mysql, easyphp

I'm trying to start Mysql DB Server but i can't, I uninstalled EasyPhp 14 still same problem.
The service MySQL is running and the log file is empty.

Comment: Check whether the port 3306 is listening. Also in mysql data floder for err file where you can check for error messages

Comment: I checked the file and it's empty